Unable to import firebase admin in python library
I am trying to use firebase admin's python libraries.  However when I try and import the libray using:
from firebase_admin import firestore
I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mnjuhn/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.cloud import firestore
  File "/Users/mnjuhn/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import gapic_version as package_version
  File "/Users/mnjuhn/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1.async_client import AsyncClient
  File "/Users/mnjuhn/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/async_client.py", line 43, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1.services.firestore import (
  File "/Users/mnjuhn/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/services/firestore/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .client import FirestoreClient
  File "/Users/mnjuhn/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/services/firestore/client.py", line 62, in <module>
    from google.cloud.location import locations_pb2  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/mnjuhn/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/location/locations_pb2.py", line 30, in <module>
    from google.api import annotations_pb2 as google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api/annotations_pb2.py", line 42, in <module>
    google_dot_protobuf_dot_descriptor__pb2.MethodOptions.RegisterExtension(http)
AttributeError: type object 'MethodOptions' has no attribute 'RegisterExtension'
>>> 

My version of python is 3.8.2 and I have the following libraries installed:
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
------------------------ ----------
CacheControl             0.14.1
cachetools               4.0.0
certifi                  2019.11.28
cffi                     1.17.1
chardet                  3.0.4
cryptography             43.0.3
firebase                 4.0.1
firebase-admin           6.6.0
google-api-core          2.22.0
google-api-python-client 1.7.11
google-auth              2.36.0
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.3
google-cloud-core        2.4.1
google-cloud-firestore   2.19.0
google-cloud-storage     2.18.2
google-crc32c            1.5.0
google-resumable-media   2.7.2
googleapis-common-protos 1.65.0
grpcio                   1.67.1
grpcio-status            1.67.1
httplib2                 0.17.0
idna                     2.9
msgpack                  1.0.0
pip                      24.3.1
proto-plus               1.25.0
protobuf                 5.28.3
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pycparser                2.22
PyJWT                    2.9.0
pytz                     2019.3
requests                 2.23.0
rsa                      4.0
setuptools               41.2.0
six                      1.14.0
uritemplate              3.0.1
urllib3                  1.25.8
wheel                    0.45.0


This issue was resolved by upgrading python3 to python version 3.12.7 and re-installing firebase-admin.
